# Iptables FTP Client rules

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

I have a Linux server and the default `INPUT` actions is `DROP`.
`OUTPUT` and `FORWARD` are both `ACCEPT`.

Which rule do I have to add to enabled the machine to establish an FTP session as FTP client.
The server is not an FTP-server. Here is my firewall rules.
Why I could not ping any remote machine or anything about OUTPUT.

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.12 on Wed Oct 10 15:30:17 2012
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [379:59440]
:INPUT ACCEPT [162:34762]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [5008:361967]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [5008:361967]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Oct 10 15:30:17 2012
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.12 on Wed Oct 10 15:30:17 2012
*filter
:INPUT DROP [8:528]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [201:14768]
:LOGGING - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p esp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i ppp+ -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 500 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 4500 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1701 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i ppp+ -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

COMMIT

UPDATED:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p esp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i ppp+ -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 500 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 4500 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1701 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7
-A FORWARD -i ppp+ -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a **client**, to allow FTP in passive mode, it's enough to allow back-half connections:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

though since rules processing is order-sensitive, it's up to you to put that rule in the right place in your INPUT chain.  Near the top is probably a good place.

**Edit:** OUTPUT traffic is allowed, according to the rules you've posted.  If you think it's not, it would be helpful to see the **running** ruleset not the **startup** ruleset; try `iptables -L -n -v`, and post the output of that.

As for PINGs, you're not allowing the backhalves of those in, either.  The rule I gave above should start those working, too.

Comment: The general problem is output traffic is not alloed though default OUTPUT action is ACCEPT. I have added my firewall rules. I could not even ping any machine when rules are applied.

Comment: ouput traffic IS allowed. You problem is that you are not accepting the responses. ping, like nearly all internet traffic, is two-way. You are allowing the request to go out, but not the response to come back. Try iptables -I INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT (note that this is not interface specific, whereas you have a rule doing this currently only for the loopback interface...)

Comment: Thanks, Norky, I think that's exactly what I'd already said in my edit above.  Nice to get confirmation!

Comment: Yup, I am echoing pretty much what MadHatter already said, with the small addition of "RELATED" to the rule.

Comment: I think state module is obsoleted by conntrack

Comment: In the latest kernel to which I have easy access (3.4.11 on Fedora 16), the `state` module is alive and well and living happily inside netfilter.  There is a `conntrack` module with more bells and whistles, but no indication that `state` is going away any time soon.  But if you know better, I'd value a referenced pointer.

Comment: From man iptables: "state
This  module,  when  combined with connection tracking, allows access to the connection tracking state for this packet." I.e. the iptables "state" module works *with* the conntrack module. http://www.rigacci.org/wiki/lib/exe/fetch.php/doc/appunti/linux/sa/iptables/conntrack.html

Comment: But from the same man page: "conntrack: This  module,  when combined with connection tracking, allows access to the connection tracking state for this packet/connection.".  So whatever the phrase "connection tracking" is referring to, and I admit that's unclear, it's definitely **not** the conntrack module.

Comment: I have updated the script as you said. I am able to ping from server but When I have send a request to an application running on this machine, it wait so long. When I have deactivated the iptables rule, it response immediatelly. What makes communication so slow.

Comment: mmc18, that is a *completely* separate question.  You asked how to modify your rules to allow yourself to act as an ftp client and to be able to ping out, and now you're asking about access to applications running on your server.  Can we establish if the FTP/PING thing is sorted, then you might want to consider a separate question about your server responsiveness?

Answer (score 0):

You might also need to make sure the connection tracking module for FTP is loaded, if it is not already (exactly what it is called will depend on your kernel version/distribution).